# Elasticsearch Specifying types in bulk requests is deprecated

Tags: elasticsearch

There is this warning i can't fix. This is my template for Logstash:

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["test-*"],
  "mappings": {

    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },

    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "box_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've removed the custom type i had around "properties" but i still getting this message:

> "type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2020-01-23T14:37:46,627+05:00",
>   "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.a.b.BulkRequestParser",
>   "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "docker-node",
>   "message": "[types removal] Specifying types in bulk requests is
>   deprecated."

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: And this "type" from "properties" removal does not help either. And i actually need this field...

Comment: Can you show how you're sending your bulk request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you remove the type:

- From the URL of the request;
- From all actions in the body (as you already tried).